# Sharing a smart tv signal

Tags: wireless-networking, tv, smart

If I have a new, up to date in 2015, samsung smart tv with comcast cable in my LR is there a way to use screen mirroring / wi-fi to watch that movie in my kitchen...on my tablet or on another smart tv?

Comment: Google Slingbox

Comment: Smart isn't as smart as your thinking.  You can also use hdmi splitter.

Answer (score 0):

I was using on ipad and notebook smartview for this purpose.

Windows - http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/smartview2/
- TV mirroring works.

IOS - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/samsung-smart-view/id858283863?mt=8
- unfortunately lately after updating the IOS app the TV mirroring feature was removed.